# Scroll Progress Bar for a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Scroll Progress Bar to let the user know how long a post is. The first approach was to calculate the height of the entire site with $(document).height and it works.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var wintop = $(window).scrollTop();
var docheight = $(document).height(); 
var winheight = $(window).height();
var scrolled = (wintop/(docheight-winheight))*100;

$('.scroll-line').css('width', (scrolled + '%'));
});
```

Now I'm trying to get it work only with a specific div, not with the entire site scroll. I've tried replacing **$(window)** or **$(document)** with my container, but it doesn't work.

In the next demo, you can see the bar working fine to measure the entire site scroll progress, but I only want to measure the progress of *scroll-progress-begins-here* div. Any help would be great.

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/iEbyGeek/pen/PRZdpV)

Answer (score 3):

Change your javascript to this

```
//capture scroll any percentage
$(window).scroll(function(){
var pos = $(".scroll-progress-begins-here").offset();
var wintop = $(window).scrollTop() - pos.top;
var dvHeight = $(".scroll-progress-begins-here").height();
var scrolled = (wintop/(dvHeight))*100;

$('.scroll-line').css('width', (scrolled + '%'));
});
```

Comment: Do you know why the scroll bar is not width:100% when the scroll has ended in the specific div?

Comment: The width never gets to 100% with this example because it is based upon when the content of the div you are keeping progress on scrolls off screen, not when the scroll bar passes the content. The page bottom comes before that div is fully off screen, so it can't get to 100% in this instance.

Comment: Is there a way to get the 100% width?

Comment: You could put a spacer after the paragraph you’re tracking so that the content can fully scroll off the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to insert scrollbar at specific div

```css
.container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [pace js](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) library for progress bar

http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

this is best way to implement progress bar in our website

Answer (score 0):

```js
//capture scroll any percentage
$(window).scroll(function(){
var wintop = $(window).scrollTop();
var docheight = $(document).height(); 
var winheight = $(window).height();
var scrolled = (wintop/(docheight-winheight))*100;
  
$('.scroll-line').css('width', (scrolled + '%'));
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow:hidden;
}
header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

}
.header-proper{
  width: 80%;
    overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  .logo{
    font-family: "HelveticaNeueBlack", "HelveticaNeue-Black", "Helvetica Neue Black", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", 'TeXGyreHerosBold', "Arial Black", sans-serif; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    .blue{
      color: blue;
    }
    
  }
}
.scroll-line{
  height: 2px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  background: blue;
  width: 0%;
}
.main{
    overflow:auto;
  height:75vh;
  position:absolute;
  top:80px;
}
.content{
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  width: 80%;
}
.headline{
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 66px;
}

.scroll-progress-begins-here {
  background-color: rgba(245,166,35,0.50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="header-proper">
    <h1 class="logo">Scroll<span class="blue"> Progress Bar</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-line"></div>
</header>
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <h3>Tristique Aenean Etiam Cras</h3>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
    <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    
    <div class="scroll-progress-begins-here">
      <h1>Scroll Progress must begins here</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>Ullamcorper Aenean Ornare</li>
      <li>Ridiculus Lorem Malesuada Consectetur</li>
      <li>Aenean Tristique Sit Lorem Purus</li>
      <li>Vehicula Egestas Mollis Cursus Nibh</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
    <h3>Bibendum Aenean Dapibus Tristique</h3>
      <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
    <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Ullamcorper Aenean Ornare</li>
      <li>Ridiculus Lorem Malesuada Consectetur</li>
      <li>Aenean Tristique Sit Lorem Purus</li>
      <li>Vehicula Egestas Mollis Cursus Nibh</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
    <h2>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</h2>
    <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
    <h3>Tristique Aenean Etiam Cras</h3>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
    <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
    <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Ullamcorper Aenean Ornare</li>
      <li>Ridiculus Lorem Malesuada Consectetur</li>
      <li>Aenean Tristique Sit Lorem Purus</li>
      <li>Vehicula Egestas Mollis Cursus Nibh</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
    <h3>Bibendum Aenean Dapibus Tristique</h3>
      <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
    <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Ullamcorper Aenean Ornare</li>
      <li>Ridiculus Lorem Malesuada Consectetur</li>
      <li>Aenean Tristique Sit Lorem Purus</li>
      <li>Vehicula Egestas Mollis Cursus Nibh</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
    <h3>Tristique Aenean Etiam Cras</h3>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
    <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
    <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Ullamcorper Aenean Ornare</li>
      <li>Ridiculus Lorem Malesuada Consectetur</li>
      <li>Aenean Tristique Sit Lorem Purus</li>
      <li>Vehicula Egestas Mollis Cursus Nibh</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
    <h3>Bibendum Aenean Dapibus Tristique</h3>
      <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
    <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Ullamcorper Aenean Ornare</li>
      <li>Ridiculus Lorem Malesuada Consectetur</li>
      <li>Aenean Tristique Sit Lorem Purus</li>
      <li>Vehicula Egestas Mollis Cursus Nibh</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
    <h2>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</h2>
    <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
    <h3>Tristique Aenean Etiam Cras</h3>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Donec sed odio dui. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
    <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
    <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Ullamcorper Aenean Ornare</li>
      <li>Ridiculus Lorem Malesuada Consectetur</li>
      <li>Aenean Tristique Sit Lorem Purus</li>
      <li>Vehicula Egestas Mollis Cursus Nibh</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
    <h3>Bibendum Aenean Dapibus Tristique</h3>
      <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.</p>
    <p>Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
    <p>Donec sed odio dui. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Ullamcorper Aenean Ornare</li>
      <li>Ridiculus Lorem Malesuada Consectetur</li>
      <li>Aenean Tristique Sit Lorem Purus</li>
      <li>Vehicula Egestas Mollis Cursus Nibh</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Is your problem solved?***

Comment: Just a piece of advice.You could use the code snippets feature so that others won't have to go to an external site.They would be able to your code working right away

Comment: Unfortunately not